# Akl-Toussaint throw-away heuristic for convex hull in 3D

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I am wondering whether there are any algorithms that use the Akl-Toussaint throw-away heuristic to compute the convex hull in 3D (not just as a simple pre-processing, but as the algorithmic principle or building block). And if so, what would their expected time complexity be?

Also, I am interested in experimental comparisons of such algorithms with the more traditional algorithms in 3D (e.g., Clarkson-Shor).

I would appreciate it very much if you could point me to papers or web pages that shed some light on my questions. (Or answer them directly :-) )

Comment: [Convex hull: Incremental variations on the Akl-Toussaint heuristics Simple, optimal and space-saving convex hull algorithms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.2676).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nico, for the pointer. Very interesting paper! (me being a practical computer scientist)  But does it really apply to the 3D case? To me, it seems purely focused on the 2D case.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't read the paper. From a quick look at their pseudo-code, it does seem to generalize to higher dimensions (the box segments will become box faces in 3D). But that impression might be wrong.